# Access specific index of array with Pug

Tags: node.js, express, pug

How can you display a specific item in an array with Pug?  For example:

```
      each answer in answers
         li!= answer.Response
```

Will display each item in the array. But, say I wanted just the the third item or, better yet, pass a variable for a specific index to display.  What is the syntax for this?

Comment: Have you tried `answers[0]`?

Comment: @tsvetanGanev Good idea, I tried and got the error  'Cannot read property 'Answer' of null'

Answer (score 1):

```
- const indexIwant = 2;
if answers && answers.length>indexIwant
  li=answers[indexIwant]
```

You need to ensure `answers` is not null and has at least the number of items to include the indexed item you want.

Another thing: don't use `!=` unless you know exactly what data you are handling.

Comment: @user3203772 Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to access a specific index of an array in pug:

```
 -const meals = ["breakfast", "lunch", "dinner"]
 -const favoriteDishes = ["coffee & doughnut salad","cheese danish soup","red wine","banana split sandwich"]
 -const sides = ["ranch dressing","chutney","ketchup","chocolate sauce"]
    p I reckon I will fix myself a hefty helping of #{favoriteDishes[2]} for #{meals[0]} with a side of #{sides[2]}.
```

Considering that indentation and whitespace is everything in jade / pug, this works :))